# Can any body Suggest WAP(Wireless Application Protocol) based client-server application?

Tags: wap

I am working in the WAP(Wireless Application Protocol) based application.

I want to use XHTML MP at client side and Servlet at Serverside.

Can anyone help me out using any sample application which is based on client and server.

Any Useful code or URL will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of introduction here (http://www.developershome.com/wap/xhtmlmp/). you should really read that link as it describe xhtml mp.

This (http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=jsp3) provides example of the usage of wap.

At the server side, you can read (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/wap/#WAP%20and%20Servlets) , where they provide how you implement code for serverside.